# Sql Server Find Next Most Recent Changed Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my employee history table I'm trying to find what the salary was and then what it was changed to. Each Salary change inserts a new record because the new salary is considered a new "job" so it has a start and end date attached. I can select all these dates fine but I keep getting duplicates because I can't seem to compare the current record only against its most recent prior record for that employee. (if that makes sense)

I would like the results to be along the lines of:

```
Employe Name, OldSalary, NewSalary, ChangeDate(EndDate)
Joe           40,000     42,000     01/10/2011
```

Example data looks like

```
EmployeeHistId     EmpId     Name    Salary      StartDate     EndDate
1                  45        Joe     40,000.00   01/05/2011    01/10/2011
2                  45        Joe     42,000.00   01/11/2011    NULL
3                  46        Bob     20,000.00   01/12/2011    NULL
```

Comment: Can you expect there to be only a single `NULL` EndDate for each EmpID?

Comment: But can you have ALL EndDates being null (employee left), which invalidates that as a predicate. Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Only the most recent record for each employee will have a null end date. Its sql server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swiss army ROW_NUMBER() to the rescue:

```
with cte as (
select EmployeeHistId     
  , EmpId     
  , Name    
  , Salary      
  , StartDate     
  , EndDate
  , row_number () over (
      partition by EmpId order by StartDate desc) as StartDateRank
from EmployeeHist)
select n.EmpId
  , n.Name
  , o.Salary as OldDalary
  , n.Salary as NewSalary
  , o.EndData as ChangeDate
from cte n
join cte o on o.EmpId = n.EmpId 
  and n.StartDateRank = 1
  and o.StartDateRank = 2;
```

Use outer join to get employees that never got a raise too.

These kind of queries are always tricky because of data purity issues, if StartDate and EndDate overlap for instance.

Comment: The start and end dates should not overlap but yeah I can't guarantee that. Does this solution cover that eventuality?

Comment: I was going to post the same solution as you with one differnce: Instead of sorting by StartDate, sort by `CASE EndDate WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, EndDate DESC` so you will get the most recent EndDate. Overlaps will not matter and you will include the `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the StartDate and EndDate will be same for the new job and previous job.
If thats the case try this.

```
SELECT a.Name AS EmployeeName, b.Salary AS NewSalary a.Salary AS NewSalary, a.StartDate AS ChangeDate
  FROM EMPLOYEE A, EMPLOYEE B
 WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpID
   AND a.EndDate IS NULL
   AND a.StartDate = b.EndDate
```

Comment: I like  your method but it looks like from his sample data that is not the case...

Comment: Maybe a `where a.employeehistid = b.employeehistid - 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the correlated join operator [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) which can solve these types of challenges easily

```
select a.name, curr.salary, prev.salary, prev.enddate
from employee e
cross apply ( -- to get the current
   select top(1) *
   from emphist h
   where e.empid = h.empid  -- related to the employee
   order by startdate desc) curr
outer apply ( -- to get the prior, if any
   select top(1) *
   from emphist h
   where e.empid = h.empid  -- related to the employee
     and h.EmployeeHistId <> curr.EmployeeHistId -- prevent curr=prev
   order by enddate desc) prev  -- last ended
```